# DOMException: The play() request was interrupted by a call to pause()

Tags: reactjs, next.js

I keep getting this error in the chrome dev tools but cannot find a way to fix.

any idea?

my code:

```
      const [playing, setPlaying] = useState<boolean>(false);
      const musicPlayers = useRef<HTMLAudioElement>(
        new Audio("url")
      );
      useEffect(() => {
        playing ? musicPlayers.current?.play() : musicPlayers.current?.pause();
      }, [playing]);

          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setPlaying(!playing);
            }}
          >
```

Comment: Is the `playing` state changing somewhere in your code?

Comment: Hi, yes sorry, forgot to add it

Comment: My first intuition was that the action of playing the audio also changes the state, which causes the audio to immediately pause (because the `useEffect` fires). If this is the only place you change this state, maybe it's not that. Perhaps you can check how many times the `useEffect` is fired each time you play the audio by adding some log at the beginning of the function (before the `playing ? ...` part). That's probably not the problem, I just want to make sure

Answer (score 0):

You also might consider not saving the playing state of the audio in the component's state, but rather check directly on the element.

Try something like

```
const toggleAudio = () => {
   if(musicPlayers.current?.paused && 
      musicPlayers.current?.currentTime > 0 && !musicPlayers.current?.ended) {
      musicPlayers.current?.play();
   } else {
      musicPlayers.current?.pause();
   }
}

...

 <button onClick={toggleAudio}>
```